# Make AlertDialog Custom

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I am using this code to display Alert Dialog

```
  holder.tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder nointernetconnection = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                temp);
                        nointernetconnection
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setTitle(list.get(position).getAS_name())
                                .setMessage(list.get(position).getDesc_art())
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                                                    int arg1) {



                                            }
                                        });
                        AlertDialog a = nointernetconnection.create();
                        a.show();
```

[image]

Message body is converted into scrollView automatically in case the text is more but Title text has not been viewed completely nor the title space is scrollable.

So, I want to expand the Title area & also want to make it scrollable & for this i don't wanna use custom Dialog, i want to only implement it by  AlertDialog.

Comment: use this with builder's obj- setCustomTitle(View)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923737/808940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is some what a typical hack... You don't need a custom `View` also...

```
private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final String title = "This is a Big Title. This is a Big Title. This is a Big Title. This is a Big Title. This is a Big Title. This is a Big Title. ";
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage("This is a Message. This is a Message. This is a Message. This is a Message.");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) alertDialog.getWindow()
                    .getDecorView();
            TextView textView = findTextViewWithTitle(viewGroup, title);
            if (textView != null) {
                textView.setEllipsize(null);
                textView.setMaxHeight((int) (80 * alertDialog.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)); 
                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

private TextView findTextViewWithTitle(ViewGroup viewGroup, String title) {
    for (int i = 0, N = viewGroup.getChildCount(); i < N; i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) child;
            if (textView.getText().equals(title)) {
                return textView;
            }
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vGroup = (ViewGroup) child;
            return findTextViewWithTitle(vGroup, title);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.setCustomTitle` method of the `AlertDialog.Builder` class, to specify a custom layout file for the title element of the dialog .(As this is still using the AlertDialog class and not a custom (or subclassed) dialog, I think it's a worthy answer). Like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
alert.setCustomTitle(view);
```

[Android docs reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29) `.setCustomTitle(View customTitleView)`

Or you could just make the title font a smaller size, but depending on how much content there is, it may become pointless even having the title there, if it's too small to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to use a custom title view, you can make the dialog title multiline:

```
TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
title.setSingleLine(false);
```

If you would like to have a scrolling title, or use a custom title, Then you only (good) option would be to use a custom alertdialog title. It's not very hard to apply:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("your very long title here");
builder.setCustomTitle(textView);
```

Comment: You should replace dialog with your own dialog, in your case: nointernetconnection

Answer (score 1):

Here is my customdialogclass. It has several constructors in function of what you want to display: buttons, progress, nothing more than a title and a message... Customizing the layout you will be able to have a longer title or not. You could even insert one custom textview that adopts its font size to the space avaible for it. Hope it helps.

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;
private int showButtons;
private String tit, msg, yesT, noT;
private boolean custom=false, all= false, progresss=false, spinner=false, indeterminateputted=false, indet=false;
private TextView title, subtit;
private ProgressBar progressBar, progressBar2;
private int max;
private int progress;

public OnPositiveDialogButtonClicked positive;

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {

    super(a);
    this.c = a;
    this.custom = false;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, int botones) {

    super(a);
    this.c = a;
    this.showButtons = botones;
    this.custom = false;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, int botones, String tit, String message) {

    super(a);
    this.custom = true;
    this.c = a;
    this.showButtons = botones;
    this.tit = tit;
    this.msg = message;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, String tit, String message, String yes, String no) {

    super(a);
    this.custom = true;
    this.c = a;
    this.tit = tit;
    this.msg = message;
    this.yesT = yes;
    this.noT = no;
    this.all = true;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, String tit, String message, int max, int progress) {

    super(a);
    this.progresss = true;
    this.tit = tit;
    this.msg = message;
    this.max = max;
    this.progress = progress;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, String tit, String message, int max, int progress, boolean spinner) {

    super(a);
    this.tit = tit;
    this.msg = message;
    this.max = max;
    this.progress = progress;
    this.spinner = true;
}

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, String tit, String message, boolean indet) {

    super(a);
    this.progresss = true;
    this.indeterminateputted = true;
    this.indet = indet;
    this.tit = tit;
    this.msg = message;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);
    subtit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageDialog);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.dialogProgress);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.dialogProgress2);

    if(this.indeterminateputted) this.progressBar.setIndeterminate(indet);

    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(tit!=null && tit.length()>0) title.setText(tit);
    if(msg!=null && msg.length()>0) subtit.setText(msg);
    if(yesT!=null && yesT.length()>0) yes.setText(yesT);
    if(noT!=null && noT.length()>0) no.setText(noT);
    if(showButtons==0) {

        yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(spinner) {

        subtit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(progresss) {

        subtit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setMax(max);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }
    if(all) {

        subtit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        no.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(custom){

        subtit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_yes:

        positive.onPositive(true);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_no:

        positive.onPositive(false);
        dismiss();
        break;
    default:

        break;
    }
    dismiss();
}

public void setButtonListener(OnPositiveDialogButtonClicked listener) {

    positive = listener;
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {

    if(progressBar!=null) {

        this.progress = progress;
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}

public void setMessage(String msg) {

    if(subtit!=null) subtit.setText(msg);
}

public void setTitle(String titleee) {

    if(title!=null) title.setText(titleee);
}

public int getProgress() {

    return this.progress;
}

public int getMax() {

    return this.max;
}

public void setIndeterminate(boolean indet) {

    this.progresss = true;
    this.indeterminateputted = true;
    this.indet = indet;
}
}
```

the interface for the buttons:

```
public interface OnPositiveDialogButtonClicked {

public void onPositive(boolean clickedYes);
}
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/dialogProgress"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
/>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:id="@+id/dialogProgress2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_no"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options-

1. You could create a custom dialog view and show ur content. Here is an example

   ```
           final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(CatchTheCatActivity.this);
       dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert);
       Button ok = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.button1);

       TextView title = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
       TextView content = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
       title.setText("your long title")
       content.setText("your long content");

       ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
                   dialog1.dismiss();  

           }
       });
       dialog1.show();
   ```

where R.layout.custom_alert is UI You want to show (in your case 2 textview with a button at the bottom). [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814644/custom-alert-box)

2. Use [popupwindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Here is an [example](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285)

Answer (score 1):

You can import a layout completely in a dialog, if you want u can set a title to dialog or put a text field in layout acting as title.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(your_layout_id, null);
        Builder builder = new Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);//Optional can be added in layout


        mAlertDialog = builder.create();
        mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mAlertDialog.setView(textEntryView, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can do custom alert dialog by creating custom layout.

*create a custom XML file in re/layout folder

*you can design it in your way.

*in you activity class you have to write in on create method

i home this will be useful for you.

Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

`d.setcontentview(R.layout.custom);`

//For example you have one edit text and button than you can make it by declaring

```
EditText ed = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.ed1);


Button b = (Button)d.finviewById(R.id.b1);

Button b = (Button)d.finviewById(R.id.b1);
```

//you can on click listner on button like

```
b.setOnClickListner(new .....);
```

Alert alert = d.create();
d.show();